# How to create objects outside functions with polymorphism?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to use polymorphism and create objects outside of main or any other function so that the functions are independent of the type of the objects I have. My code is as follows:

The main class:

```
class load{   //Main class
protected:
    static load **L;
    static int n, n1;
public:
    load(){};
    virtual float getpower()=0;
    static int getn();
    static load ** getL();
};

load **load::L;
int load::n; 
int load::n1;

int load::getn(){
    return n;
}

load** load::getL(){
    return L;
}
```

The child class:

```
class load1:public load{ 
private:
    float power;
public:
    load1();
    load1(int s);
    void createUnits1();
    float getpower();
}l1(0);               //Object creation

load1::load1(int s){
    createUnits1();
}

void load1::createUnits1(){
    cout<<"Give the number of type 1 objects: "<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    for (int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        load1 temp;         //Run default constructor
    }
}

load1::load1(){
    cout<<"Give the power of the device: "<<endl;
    cin>>power;
    n++;
    if (n==1){
        L=(load **)malloc(n*sizeof(load *));
    }
    else {
        L=(load **)realloc(L,n*sizeof(load *));
    }
    L[n-1]=this;
}

float load1::getpower(){
    return power;
}
```

The function of calculation:

```
float get_total_P(load **l, int num){
    float tot_power=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        tot_power+=l[i]->getpower();
    }
    return tot_power;
}
```

My main function:

```
int main() {
    load **l;
    int num;
    num=load::getn();
    l=load::getL();
    float total_P=get_total_P(l, num);
    cout<<total_P;
    return 0;
}
```

The upper code produces a segmentation fault but I can't see the reason why. The segmentation fault is on the line

```
tot_power+=l[i]->getpower();
```

So I guess my way of creating objects is wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your segfault, is that `l` doesn't point to anything valid  !

In `main()` you initialise `l` with `load::getL()`.  But this function only returns the `load::L` which has the same type and was defined as static in your load class but was never initialized.

You have coded in your derived class `load1` some initialisation code for `L`, but it is never invoqued in `main()`.

Your code has also some severe design issues:

- It's not advised to use `malloc()` and `realloc()` in C++ code.  If you create an object in C++ use `new`.  If you want some dynamic array, use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).
- You could get `L` and hence `l` initialized if you'd create some `load1` objects before calling `getL()`.  But due to your realloc, l would then risk to point to an obsolete thus invalid address, if you would create any other `load1` object before calling `get_total()`.
- It's bad practice and terrible design to request user input in a constructor.  The constructor is meant to cosntruct an object with the parameters you give him when you call him.  Imagine the user would give an invalid parameter ?  The user would be asked for input whenever a `load1` object is constucted.  Even for temporary variables,  not even speaking from the effect when you'd write load1 a[10];

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I created the new objects using **new** and it worked!